# I implemented an SVD, but sometimes it is not possible to restore the original matrix

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, svd

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np


def svd(A):
    eigvals_left, eigvecs_left = np.linalg.eig(A @ A.T)

    eigvals_right, eigvecs_right = np.linalg.eig(A.T @ A)

    sigma = np.sqrt(np.abs(eigvals_right))

    num = min(A.shape)

    sorted_indices = np.argsort(-sigma)
    sigma = sigma[sorted_indices[:num]]

    U = eigvecs_left[:, np.argsort(-eigvals_left)[:num]]
    V = eigvecs_right[:, np.argsort(-eigvals_right)[:num]]

    return U, sigma, V.T


h = np.random.rand(2, 3)

print(h)

j, k, l = svd(h)
x, y, z = np.linalg.svd(h, compute_uv=True, full_matrices=False)

print('---------------')
print(j @ np.diag(k) @ l)
print('---------------')
print(x @ np.diag(y) @ z)
print('---------------')

print(l @ z.T)
```

I am confused.In most cases, the absolute values of l and z are similar, but there is always a sign difference between 1 and z.I have sorted eigvecs correctly. The matrix obtained by multiplying the transpose of l and z is also something similar to a diagonal matrix, but the sign is sometimes positive and sometimes negative.

output1:

```
[[0.53221807 0.59786549 0.09906266]
 [0.4031512  0.38389025 0.16900433]]
---------------
[[-0.55253742 -0.55534658 -0.19184685]
 [-0.37481911 -0.44317609 -0.03963159]]
---------------
[[0.53221807 0.59786549 0.09906266]
 [0.4031512  0.38389025 0.16900433]]
---------------
[[ 1.00000000e+00  7.40766293e-17]
 [-4.02870278e-17  1.00000000e+00]]
```

output2:

```
[[0.23044744 0.86795113 0.64293873]
 [0.80871952 0.17031212 0.33708637]]
---------------
[[0.23044744 0.86795113 0.64293873]
 [0.80871952 0.17031212 0.33708637]]
---------------
[[0.23044744 0.86795113 0.64293873]
 [0.80871952 0.17031212 0.33708637]]
---------------
[[-1.00000000e+00 -2.56188682e-16]
 [-4.53777597e-16  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign (and more generally the phase) of the eigenvectors is arbitrary, two different algorithms may output different signs. In the case of an SVD, the signs of the singular vectors is a gauge freedom in the SVD definition.

If you have an SVD `M = U @ S @ V`, where `S` is diagonal and `U` and `V` are unitaries, you any sign change on `U` columns and `V` rows also gives an SVD.

```py
n = 10
M = np.random.random((n, n))
U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(M)
S = np.diag(s)
print(np.allclose(M, U @ S @ V))
random_signs = 1 - 2 * (np.random.random(n) > 0.5)
D = np.diag(random_signs)
U2 = U @ D
V2 = D @ V
print(np.allclose(M, U2 @ S @ V2))
```

In the absence of degeneracy in the singular values, this is the only degree of freedom in an SVD. Some algorithm have been proposed to fix this gauge.

For more details on SVD gauge, see e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037704278890386X?via%3Dihub

Comment: Thank you very much. Since I have solved the left and right singular matrices separately, U and V are affected by different D. Therefore, it is impossible to restore the original matrix. I'm not sure if my understanding is correct?

Comment: That was the issue in your code yes. If you solve independently for right and left eigenvectors, then there is no way to make the signs match between left and right. But you don't have to: A @ A.T is positive real symmetric, left and right eigenvectors are the same, you can use `s0, U0 = np.linalg(A @ A.T)` `s = np.sqrt(s0)`.
This is algorithm behind scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(solver=arpack).

Comment: OK! I just need ` VT = np.linalg.inv(np.diag(sigma)) @ U.T @ A`.This solution  can't work correctly if S is sigular, but enough! Thanks!

Comment: You can even do better: assuming no zero singular value, you get the inverse for free. If `A @ A.T = U0 * s0 @U0.T` then `inv(A @ A.T) = U0 * s0**-1 @ U0.T`. In practice, one needs a cutoff for small singular values, replace 1/vanishing singular value by 0, yielding the (Moore–Penrose) pseudo-inverse.